# Python why the second 'res += str(count) + n[i]' need in this question

Tags: python

```
def countAndSay(self, n):
    res = "1"
    for _ in xrange(n-1):
        res = self.helper(res)
    return res

def helper(self, n):
    count, i, res = 1, 0, ""
    while i < len(n) - 1:
        if n[i] == n[i+1]:
            count += 1
        else:
            res += str(count) + n[i]
            count = 1
        i += 1
    res += str(count) + n[i] //this line code 
    return res
```

My question is what the second "res += str(count) = n[i]" do in this code

Answer (score 0):

The last line does the operation for i=len(n)-1. As the loop will go for i values less than that. At that line value of i will be len(n)-1. As for that value we can't check the condition `if n[i] == n[i+1]:` but we want to do the operation